# Is "I lost it" clear without adding more to it?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

*I lost my temper and started yelling at them. It was unforgiveable. **I lost it** and I shouldn't have.*

Is the phrase "I lost it" clear without adding more to it? Is it perfectly natural to use in contexts like this?

Comment: In that context, yes it's clear. Without the context, it could mean any number of things.

Comment: To lose it means to get angry and shout.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's clear. "I lost it" (meaning I lost my temper/composure/self-control) is often used as a phrase in itself.

Answer (score 1):

In that context it is clear. It means "I lost my temper".  It is rather casual, so if this is a formal apology then "I lost my temper" would be better.

Without the context, it could just mean "There was something that I was unable to find."